# Ubuntu Server guest doesn't work with more than one network on Virtualbox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I have two virtual machines set up on my Virtualbox: a Debian 8.7.1 and a Ubuntu Server 17.04 one. My host is Windows 10.

I made it work the host-only adapter from Virtualbox on Debian by simply turning it on the option on Virtualbox and it worked like magic. However on Ubuntu Server it doesn't display the new network on `ifconfig`. I tried with DHCP on and off.

I tried to set it up manually on `/etc/network/interfaces` with a static IP by the name of `eth1` or `enp0s4` (the NAT interface has the name of `enp0s3` and no results.

However, I tired to swich places with the adapters and I found out that `enp0s3` was now the host-only network, but the NAT network was gone. So apparently the guest doesn't know more than two networks (the `enp0s3` and the loopback).

How to fix this?

Comment: Could you post the configuration file of you'r Ubuntu VM ?
It is .vbox file.
Default it is can be located here in windows. ~/VirtualBox VMs/NAME_OF_VM/NAME_OF_VM.vbox Example location: ~/VirtualBox VMs/MyTestVm/MyTestVm.vbox

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and discovered that the second interface shows up in the output of `ip addr show`, but not `ifconfig`. I don't know the technical reason for this, but `ifconfig` has been [more-or-less deprecated](https://serverfault.com/questions/633087/where-is-the-statement-of-deprecation-of-ifconfig-on-linux) on Linux for a while.

On my machine, my second interface is named `enp0s8`, so it's probably present on your VM, but with a different name than you expected.

Comment: well, `enp0s8` (I know that I wasn't crazy when that showed up on the boot) is listed on `ip addr show` but for some reason is was down. I turned it up and now shows on `ifconfig` too

Comment: however `enp0s8` doesn't get a valid IPv4 for some reason and nor NAT or host-only works

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem. You should probably open a new question and include the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` and the output of `ip addr show`. 

If my answer solved your original problem of not being able to locate your second interface, I'd be grateful if you'd mark it as accepted.